# C pointer. Getting the null list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Below Code for inserting data after a specified node. When I do a print*** of the node I am getting the null list.

Also, pls suggest some other I/O method.

head: 1 2 3 4 (linked list with four values)

Inserting the data:

```
insertAfter(struct Node *head){
    int data, insert;
    struct Node *temp = NULL;
    temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    scanf("%d", &data); //value in the linked list
    scanf("%d", &insert); // data to be inserted 

    while (head != NULL){
        if (head->data == data){
            temp->data = insert;
            temp->next = n->next;
            head->next = temp;
            printf("data matched \n");
       }
       head = head->next;
    }
    printList(head); //print*** of the node
}
```

Printing the linkedList:

```
 void printList(struct Node *head){
     while (head != NULL){
     printf("\n %d", head->data);
     head = head->next;
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] and an example of input and actual and expected output.

Comment: `while (n != NULL) { ...} printList(n);` `n` will always be`NULL` after that loop (assuming it terminates).

Comment: _"pls suggest some other I/O method"_: why? What problem do you have with your I/O? But anyway, please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: I think there should be some other format specifier used to print the pointer?

Comment: @vineetsagar your code does not print a pointer, it prints an `int` (`head->data` is an `int`, `head` is a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
insertAfter(struct Node *head){
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // one line is enough 
                                                     // and casting is useless.    
    int data, insert;
    scanf("%d", &data);
    scanf("%d", &insert);

    struct Node *current = head;                     // head stays at head of list

    while (current != NULL){
        if (current->data == data){
            temp->data = insert;
            temp->next = n->next;
            current->next = temp;
            printf("data matched\n");
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    printList(head);
}
```

The `printList`  function seems correct though it is odd that you print the newline beforehead, I'd use this: `"%d\n"` instead of this: `"\n %d"`.

Disclaimer: this is untested code. All comments are mine.

BTW: it is bad design to do the input inside the `insertAfter` function. The signature of this function should be:

```
insertAfter(struct Node *head, int data, int insert);
```

and the `scanf` calls should be done before you call `insertAfter`:

```
scanf("%d", &data); //value in the linked list
scanf("%d", &insert); // data to be inserted 
insertAfter(head, data, insert);
```

Comment: OT: `struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` alternative: `struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Comment: Note that `temp` leaks memory if `current->data == data` is never true and potentially worse, it repeats if `current->data == data` is true more than once.